# connect to SSMS SQL using Azure Active Directory in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, ssms

actually i am looking for any npm module or any way to connect to the ssms sql using aad in nodejs.
we usually connect to ssms using windows authentication, but i want the user to enter the credentials and validate it with AAD and use those credentials to login to SSMS.

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server Management Studio? What are you trying to do with SSMS from a Node.js application? Or are you looking to connect to an Azure SQL database from the Node.js application?

Comment: Yes i mean SQL server management studio. i have a nodejs api which connect ssms using windows authentication , but i want the username and password from user and validate them using AAD and if it is valid , i need to connect to ssms using those username and password .